# Is the Composite Video connector on the Raspberry Pi unusually wired

Tags: video, composite, rca

I'm trying to add a video player to an elderly TV. I have OSMC working well with HDMI, but I struggled to get it to work on **Composite** output. It's **Raspberry Pi 3 B+ v1.2.** Having been through the numerous posts, suggesting modifications to the config.txt, I decided that the audio buzz I could hear on the right channel was more than just noise, and swapped the Audio Right for the Video. Hey presto. Clear sound and Picture.
I have subsequently tried several 3.5mm / RCA leads. If **swap red / yellow**, they all work. One of them even has the yellow labelled as "Comp Vid", but it only works if I connect the "Audio R" intot he video.

So, the question is: is the Raspberry Pi atypical or unusual? Is it simply that there is no particular standard and coincidence that my three cables are all the same (inappropriate) configuration?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are at least 5 different combinations of TRRS cable that are wired differently. You need to make sure you get the correct one.

https://www.raspberrypi-spy.co.uk/2014/07/raspberry-pi-model-b-3-5mm-audiovideo-jack/

Best option is to buy a cable from a Pi supplier that stated Raspberry Pi compatible.

How to test a cable:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UEWs_bxDWic

Comment: I was afraid you'd say that! I've been working in Audio / Video equipment for about 25 years and I have NEVER seen a cable were white/red is NOT audio left/right, nor a cable where "other" is not video. The confusion is with TRRS. There doesn't seem to be a standard for that end.